# Examples of statements which, if true, have unreasonably long proofs

Tags: logic, proof-theory

In $\mathbf{Q}$ (or any theory strong enough to encode $\mathbf{Q}$), there exist true statements whose proofs cannot be written in under $N$ symbols for a fixed $N$. For example, if $N = 1000000$ take the statement

```
This sentence has no proof with less than 1000000 symbols.
```

This can be formalized into the language of $\mathbf{Q}$ (or whatever sufficient strong theory we're using) and it has to be true, assuming consistency of our theory.

I'm interested in examples of natural-sounding statements such that we provably know that if the statement is true, then it's formal proof has an unreasonable lower bound on length. Since "unreasonable" is fairly subjective, lets say proofs that couldn't be written down over the lifespan of the entire universe if we could write a symbol a second.

Comment: Not a definite answer, hence the comment instead of answer, but if I had to spitball I'd probably guess either something with Ramsey theory or Busy Beaver functions?

Comment: Fermat's last theorem or the 4-colour-theorem should come close if you break it down into elementary steps. However, the lower bound is the trapdoor here. The proofs we know are incredibly long, but that doesn't mean they are the shortest possible. It is generally pretty hard to prove lower bounds since these are non-existence statements.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what exactly is $\mathbf{Q}$?

Comment: Maybe: the [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of a program that do $1+1 = 2$ is quite shorter than its 379 pages formal prove: [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwbZaTjXo-s)

Comment: @Nicolino [Robinson Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic). It's Peano Arithmetic, but without the axiom of induction.

Comment: I don’t think any such natural sounding theorems exist, but to prove it would take more than a million characters :-p.

Comment: I do not know whether this answers your question, not sure what precisely would satisfy you concretely. However, your intuition relates to the "self-referential paradox" and a weaker form of Gödel's incompleteness theorem. Gödel's theorem states that in any consistent formal system that is strong enough to express Peano arithmetic (such as , I suppose) there exist statements that are true but cannot be proved within the system. Similarly, the Paris-Harrington theorem may provide a good example too, a strong form of the finite Ramsey theorem.